# How get the wrong entity in saveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

When I can `saveChanges()` for some entities, and one entity was wrong, I go to `exception` catch and I want to insert to Log the `stateEntity` that was wrong, If I will get the specific entity I can do it.
The method of save use for **add**,**update** and **remove**

**Can I catch the wrong entity?**

My save method:

```
  public long save(IResponse res, Context context)
            {
                try
                {

                    foreach (Entity ent in response.Entities)
                    {
                        context.Entry(ent).State = ent.getEntityState();
                    }

                    return context.SaveChanges();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string errorMessages = ex.InnerException.InnerException.ToString();            
                    res.ExceptionDBDesc = errorMessages;
                    res.WrongEntState= ???    //add/modify/remove

                }
```

Comment: your question is not clear as of now , please improve it

Comment: I believe he is asking if he can save the object itself that causes the exception. You can only do that if you reference the object outside the try statement. The references inside the try statement are disposed? I believe? When an exception occurs.

Comment: I need the entity state just for information

Comment: I don't understand what you want. "one entity was wrong", what is "wrong"? Why don't you just break out of the `foreach` when an entity is "wrong"?

Comment: Example you try insert entity with primary key that already exists

Comment: If you get that, it usually due to context mismanagement. Either via threads or instance passing that doesn't work as intended. We need more code to be able to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

**Try it :**

```html
try
{
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
{
    Exception raise = dbEx;
    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}", validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(), validationError.ErrorMessage);
            //raise a new exception inserting the current one as the InnerException
            raise = new InvalidOperationException(message , raise);
        }
    }
    throw raise;
}
```

Comment: Suggestions to try something don't qualify as an answer. Also, this doesn't do what was asked.

Comment: @GertArnold Perhaps not directly, but the "validationErrors.Entry.Entity"
line should provide the Entity in question yes?

Comment: The question isn't about validation errors. But "try this" isn't an answer. Either answer the question with confidence and proper explanation or else just suffice with a suggestion in a comment (which may lead to an answer later). A "try this" answer doesn't have much value for future readers.